# I need to have a connection string that changes for new devices

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, local-database

So I'm using this post as a last resort, newcomer here, my connection string currently looks like this for my local MSSQL database:

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\steve\OneDrive\Desktop\UNIT 5 CS\MonmouthCanoeAndActivityCentre\MonmouthCanoeAndActivityCentre\.vs\MonmouthCanoeAndActivityCentre\.vs\MonmouthCanoeAndActivityCentre\v16\WorkerLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
```

which is of course incredibly clunky and also hard coded to my personal laptop. My problem is that I want to be able to run the connection on any new device I send the project to without them having to change the directory of the connection string themselves.

Any advice would be helpful, I'm not incredible at visual basic either so sorry if I question.

Comment: This is why you don't hard-code connection strings. You store them in the config file and then they can be edited to anything after deployment.

Comment: Unfortunately its my first time using VB, if I knew how to do whatever you just said I probably would have :( @user18387401

Comment: It's not just a matter of knowing how to do something but rather knowing what to do. Now that you know the what, you can do some research for yourself to find out the how.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to hopefully help some poor future soul.

the new connection string is:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" & Application.StartupPath & "InsertFileNameHere.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
```

The .mdf file of your database has to be in the same place as your `Application.StartupPath` but you can find this with a simple:

```
Dim location As String = Application.StartupPath
    MessageBox.Show(location)
```

and a test button to activate the above ^